# Cannot boot using live CD in grub rescue mode

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I think I destroyed my laptop using `fdisk`. I had an unallocated part of my hard drive from an old Windows install. I tried to get it back for my Ubuntu, but I lost everything somehow.

My screen shows the following:

```
error: no such partition. 
Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) 

grub rescue>
```

I can't even boot from the installation CD. Nothing works. What can I do to make my laptop boot up using the live CD?

Answer (score -1):

To me, this looks like your computer is set up such that your HD is the first boot device. If that's the case or if you're unsure, you should check in your BIOS if your CD / DVD drive is set before the HD in the boot order.

Comment: My bios shows: Boot Config: External Device Boot and Network Boot both Disabled. Boot Priority: Internal Optical Disk Drive; Internal Hard Disk Drive; External Device; and Network. I think the boot priority is correct.  And I've tried other Linux distro CDs, but nothing will boot up.

Comment: Seems correct. Can you see (by means of an LED) or hear your computer accessing the CD /  DVD drive? If not, it might have some kind of defect.

Comment: The CD is spinning at boot up. But stalls out and the grub rescue screen comes up.